# Remove substring from filename in jenkins groovy script

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-groovy

Hi I am trying to remove substring "-unsigned" from filename in jenkins pipeline script.

where filePattern app/build/outputs/**/*-release*.apk".

I wrote below groovy script

```
        findFiles(glob: filePattern).each { file ->
            sh """
            mv ${file.path} "${file.path//-unsigned/}"
            """
        }
```

getting error unexpected char : 0XFFFF.

Can suggest where exactly I am missing. or suggest how to remove substring from file name in groovy.

Comment: issue in this expression `${file.path//-unsigned/}` but it's not clear what you are trying to do

Comment: Where is the  "-unsigned" in "app/build/outputs/**/-release.apk"? provide a before / expected after example.

Comment: Have .apk files at path app/build/outputs/apk/variant/app-variant-release-unsigned.apk and want to remove the string "-unsigned" from filename. Have variants such as prod, qa, stage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

not sure it's the best way to rename files however:

```
findFiles(glob: filePattern).each { file ->
   sh """
      mv ${file.path} "${file.path - '-unsigned'}"
      """
}
```

---

issue in your code that you have `//` in this expression `${file.path // ...}`

and compiler could take it as a single line comment

try to run this in groovy console:

```js
"""
${'abc' //no matter what here}
"""
//comment here
```

^^^ compilation error: unexpected char: 0xFFFF

Comment: Thanks @daggett. It removed the string.

Answer (score 0):

See [bash(1) - Linux man page](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/bash.1.html#EXPANSION):

> **EXPANSION**
>
> [...]
>
> **Parameter Expansion**
>
> [...]
>
> ${*parameter*/*pattern*/*string*}
>
> **Pattern substitution**. [...] *Parameter* is expanded and the longest match of *pattern* against its value is replaced with *string*.

So it should be `"${file.path/-unsigned//}"`.